# Validate both the registry key value, and if the key exists

Tags: loops, batch-file, registry, registrykey, sid

I made this batch script to validate multiple reg keys listed inside a `.txt file`, and within in multiple SID's.

```
ECHO on
cd %~dp0
if not exist "REPORTS" mkdir REPORTS
echo.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F  "tokens=2 delims=\" %%t in ('reg query HKU ^| findstr /v "_Classes"') do ( 
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (c:\users\admin\desktop\RegKeysSID_0x0A.txt) do  (
        FOR /F "tokens=3  delims= " %%m in ('REG QUERY "HKU\%%t\%%a"') DO (
            If "%%m" EQU "0x0" ( echo OK  HKU\%%t\%%a  %%m>>"REPORTS\USER_SID_Keys_.txt"
            ) else ( echo NOK  HKU\%%t\%%a  %%m>>"REPORTS\USER_SID_Keys_.txt" )
        )
    )
)
pause

exit
```

Inside `RegKeysSID_0x0A.txt`, (just one reg key to scan quickly):

```
System\GameConfigStore" /v GameDVR_Enabled
```

It uses `reg query`, but when the key does not exist, this gives me an error. I dont know how to set that error to a variable, or, if the key is not present, print an error to the report file.

I did try these...

- When the key is `0x0` it's okay, if the key is `0x1` it's not okay.
  However, when the key is not defined/created, I cannot export nothing to the file.
- I tried the errorlevel with no success, it was always `0`.

I'm not an expert with Windows batch files, and I'm stuck with this issue.

Comment: By saying *When the key is `0x0` it's okay, if the key is `0x1` it's not okay* do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: If your users aren't logged in, their registry hive will not be loaded, and you will not be able to read their key data. The Security Identifiers, (SID's) with the `_Classes` suffix are usually the contents of the current user's Classes. The data in `HKEY_USERS\<SID>_Classes` should therefore mirror those within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` of the logged in user. You are looking in the wrong place for data which will not be there anyhow. You'll have to determine the SID for each target user, and load the appropriate hive from its usual location , query the data and unload the hive.

Comment: that works OK. I mean if the key not exist i want to export that missing key with "Missing status" to the report file.

Comment: @Compo I know that. I want to check the value its ok or not and if the key exist  and export that data to report file. This is for all present SID (_Classes not included)

Comment: What I'm telling you is that all you could possibly do is to check for information in loaded registries, and that's most probably going to just be the currently logged in user only. A proper solution would be to load the relevant hive for each of your target users if you're wanting to check the information in their user keys. Obviously this will require that you're running the script elevated or as a user with sufficient permissions to access and read the users' hives.

Comment: I know its an alternative... load the hive for itch user but for that solution i have to know witch Hives (users names) i have to load. but with this the script will check all users with the present SID folder in the reg.

Comment: That's correct, and what I'm trying to tell you. At the moment it's unlikely that more than one user has their hive loaded, so you may as well just be checking for, in this case, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore" /v GameDVR_Enabled`. It is also unlikely, that you'll be wanting to check inside all SID's anyhow, keys like `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`, `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19`, `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20`, and `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` are probably for users which are irrelevant for your purposes.

Comment: @Compo I need that. I have a big list of reg keys to check and create the report included the HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT, HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19, HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20, and HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18.

Comment: @ZDC, I do not believe that you do! The `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` subkey is the exact same as the `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` subkey and is for the LocalSystem account, `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19` is for the LocalService account, and similarly `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20` is the NetworkService account. None of these accounts are regular users and will inevitably not carry the information you say you're looking for.

Comment: `reg query` probably returns an `ErrorLevel`, but since you are executing this command in the scope of `for /F` you cannot detect it in your script...

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help.

Comment: I found a solution... export the complete reg keys (for all pretended SID) with "reg query sufix" and the errorlevel  condition to a new cmd file and execute with vbs script and run  like a charme.